# Plotly Dash/ Apache Kafka - I would like to see a graph plotting live rather than appearing when finished plotting

Tags: python, apache-kafka, plotly-dash

I have viewed live updating of streaming graphs in plotly however this is not exactly what I am looking to do. I have a graph component which gets populated on the click of a button component. In the callback to update the graph an object is created and a method is called on from that class which returns a stream of 15 values using apache kafka streaming producer. I then have the apache kafka consumer in the callback which receives the values one by one. However I am trying to get these values to appear on my dash graph one by one also. I tried using an interval component but this appears to be just recalling the function every second meaning the script gets stuck recalling the function and does not do anything.

Would be grateful for any help on this and can provide more detail if necessary.

Comment: Hi more detail would be great, a code snippet perhaps . but from what I read you want to do a callback -> pub/sub function rather than an interval, as soon as you get an event from kafka you want to async push an event to a listener this will ensure its not blocking .. but with a snippet i can assist further

Comment: @Gabriel I have included snippet

Comment: Just a few questions , how come you are reconstructing the consumer on click ? , what I would do is construct them on init of the constructor .. so just below some_object.simulate()  then you should also thread the consumer using multiprocessing.Process just as you do with the producer , then when the consumer triggers it should update the data on a list , then when your interval hits you just read from that list or you could just push it directly if you have smart binding - does this make sense ? give it a try if still no luck I can post my solution - stream data is always open & background

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Gabriel, I tried this and I still am getting the problem with the creation of the object inside the simulate_and_populate_graph function, it appears to be trying to create the object 6 times but I only want it created once

Comment: no problem , the consumer should not be created in the callback function. what I will do a working example for you and post it with some comments. check back tomorrow :)

Comment: I have placed a simple example for you to reference below with some explanation of what's going wrong in your code. if you still get stuck then I will add a ploty dash version to illustrate the concept using the whole lib, below should be good  though don't think is necessary to make a complex one:)

Comment: @Gabriel thank you for the example this definitely helps, I'm still slightly confused on how to populate the dash graph object with this queue. Does the figure component of the graph get populated inside the while loop? And then where is the return statement for the callback returning the figure?

Comment: @Gabriel another issue I am facing when applying this in the callback is the use of the n_intervals, I get a memory error, it seems that my simulate function is causing this memory error

Comment: Hi Alison, off hand there are a few structure issues I see,  is there a reason you have imports in the callback?  , your callback function should have no imports , no threads , no consumers , no producers . all it should do is ask the consumer what the latest data is , and ask the producer to send the data if needed.

Comment: I will update the solution which will help you, please perhaps add this issue to the question. it has to do with how you are running the objects. please also accept the answer when you are happy with it also click the little arrow on the side if you are finding these comments helpful. you are calling a constructor on every interval you just want to call only the send

Comment: regarding the queue there is no while loop for you, its just a quick callback example , you will use your interval , just pull an item from the queue on each interval and return it  , thats all you need to do

Comment: @Gabriel thank you I will be sure to mark your answer as helpful once you update it with the callback example. My producer is inside the callback as my callback triggers the simulate function which produces the data needed to populate my graphs. So this callback takes n_clicks of a button as input aswell as other inputs from dropdowns it then calls on the simulate function on a simulator object using these inputs when the button is pressed. So my confusion is how I can do this outside of the callback if it is the button that triggers the simulate function?

Comment: seems like you accepted another answer did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Streams you will want to place the consumer in its own thread. you are already placing the producer in a thread , I would also suggest not joining the producer to the main thread either

what you want to do is place the consumer in a thread and use a queue or a thread safe data structure or locking , a queue is thread safe so you can extract the data as it comes if you like

you also want to run the threads in a def or startup , and not on a callback, each time on the callback you will just ask for the latest item on the queue and can set an interval to 100ms or so dep on pref

I have a simple example below :

- the while loop will be your callback interval - im using a while for time
- you must set the consumer outside the callback - otherwise you build it again and again, place the consumer outside the scope of the callback and run it on startup , below I used main.

```
    from time import sleep
    from json import dumps
    from kafka import KafkaConsumer
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
    import os
    
    
    
    def consumer(q):
    
        consumer_obj = KafkaConsumer('test')
        for message in  consumer_obj:
         q.put(message.value)
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target=consumer, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        while True:
            print(q.get())
            sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The consumer loop is infinite, and you cannot iterate the same consumer object twice for the same set of records. You cannot use list-comprehension, so you need to store the lists separately

The following is untested, but shows the general idea of what you would need to do

```
x = []
y = []

LIMIT = 15

for r in consumer_obj:

  if len(x) >= LIMIT:
    del x[0]
  if len(y) >= LIMIT:
    del y[0]

  x.append(r.value['day'])
  y.append(r.value['biomass'])
  
  # TODO: Update graph 
  data = {"data": [
          {"x": x,"y": y, 
          "type": "lines",
        }]
```

There is a project here using Bokeh intstead of Plotly - https://github.com/Aakash282/kafka-bokeh-dashboard

---

Or you could just use Kafka Connect to write to a SQLite database, and make your plot use that and have that update periodically